# What is causing the horizontal scrolling in my responsive WordPress layout?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am developing a website using WordPress and a modified version of the Quark theme. It is going pretty well, but one problem I am running into is that on screens narrower than 790px, a horizontal scroll appears at the bottom of the browser and I can't figure out what is causing it.

Here is the URL: http://yousavewithsolar.emorydayclients.com

I know there are other responsive issues w/ the homepage, but those I know how to fix. This one is the one giving me fits.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your body tag :

```
body {

  overflow-x: hidden;

}
```

Comment: the solution worked fine for me till I found that this blocked the scroll from mouse and laptop's trackpad in the live environment. The site work perfectly fine in local though. Any solutions?